# Programmatically move AutoscrollBar

Tags: c#, autoscroll

How can i programmatically move the `AutoScrollBar` horizonatally or vertically. I wanna be able to move it while pressing any arrow key.

I tried to change `this.AutoScrollPosition`, but nothing happens, and `AutoScrollPosition` kinda keeps negative values. When i tried what will happen `OnScroll` event i received positive value for the new value.

I dont want to use `ScrollIntoView(Control control)`, because i am not working with controls, i work with pure `Graphics`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Value property of the scrollbar:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.value(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)